# Is it possible to detect when a DMA channel on a Cortex M3 goes idle?

Tags: arm, embedded, cortex-m, dma

I've just taken over a project developing C code for an STM32 Cortex M3 microcontroller.

An issue that I immediately have is that I have a free running DMA channel that transfers data between 2 USARTs, but on occasions data from another source needs to be sent to the destination USART.

Is there any way to detect when a DMA is busy transferring data or idle, or are there any interrupts triggered when a transfer is complete.

Many thanks for any responses,

Dave

Comment: This isn't strictly off-topic, but if you don't get the answer you're hoping for here, you may get a better one from Electronics StackExchange.

Comment: Just to add another bit to this - is it possible that if a peripheral has 2 DMA channels streaming data to it that the DMA controller arbitrates between the DMA channels so that only one writes to the location at a time?

Comment: Thanks Polynomial - I will have a look there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I do to check if the DMA operation has completed:

```
DMA_Cmd(DMA2_Channel5, ENABLE); // start
while (!DMA_GetFlagStatus(DMA2_FLAG_TC5)); // wait to finish
DMA_ClearFlag(DMA2_FLAG_TC5); // clear flag (needed?)
```

Answer (score 3):

DMA completion can be both polled or interrupt driven.  The details are in the reference manual for your specific part - *"STM32 Cortex-M3"* is not specific enough to narrow it down to the document you need, but you can download it from [ST's website](http://www.st.com/internet/mcu/subclass/1169.jsp).

The simplest way to implement DMA is to use the [STM32 Stanadard Peripheral Library](http://www.st.com/internet/com/SOFTWARE_RESOURCES/SW_COMPONENT/FIRMWARE/stm32f10x_stdperiph_lib.zip).  It includes example projects for all peripherals including both DMA polling and DMA interrupt examples for the USART.  Your tool-chain may already include the library, but possibly not all the examples.  Even if you already have the library, it is a good idea to check that it is the latest revision.